# CsvHelper - write to SQL Database with mapping

Tags: c#, csvhelper

The CSVHelper .NET library seems fantastic so far, but the documentation is a little lacking for a pseudo-beginner like myself.

I need to read a csv file and write the results to our SQL Server database.  For the table I'm writing to, I need to map to its columns from the CSV columns, including some concatenation of multiple fields to one.

This is what I have for reading the csv file:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))          
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
            header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");
        var records = csv.GetRecords<EntityCsv>().ToList();
    }
}
```

My `EntityCsv` class contains property names for all columns of the csv file.

Then, I also have a class called `TaskEntity` which contains the property names and types for the destination database table (although I'm unclear as to whether I need this).

Finally, per advice from a colleague, I have a method set up to make use of `SQLBulkCopy` as thus:

```
public void AddBulk(List<TaskEntity> entities)
{
    using (var con = GetConnection())
    {
        SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        bulk.BatchSize = 2000;
        bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        bulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.CsvExports";
        bulk.WriteToServer(entities.AsDataTable());
        bulk.Close();
    }
}
```

I borrowed that code block from him and would theoretically run that method as the final step.

But I know I'm missing a step in between, and that is mapping the fields from the csv to the SQL server field.  I'm scratching my head at how to implement this step.

So let's say for simplicity's sake I have 3 columns in the csv file, and I want to map them to 2 columns of the SQL table as follows:

```
CsvColumn1 -> SQLtableColumn1
CsvColumn2 + CsvColumn3 -> SQLtableColumn2
```

How would I go about accomplishing this with CsvReader and C#?  I have explored the Mapping section of the CSVReader documentation but everything I'm seeing in there seems to refer to mapping column names from an input file to names in an output file.  I don't see anything there (nor anywhere on the Google) that speaks specifically to taking the input file and exporting its rows to a SQL database.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `ClassMap` to map the csv columns to the sql table columns and skip the `CsvEntity` class.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))          
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
            header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TaskEntityMap>();

        var records = csv.GetRecords<TaskEntity>().ToList();
    }
}

public class TaskEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SqlTableColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string SqlTableColumn2 { get; set; }
}

public sealed class TaskEntityMap : ClassMap<TaskEntity>
{
    public TaskEntityMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn1).Name("CsvColumn1");
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn2).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn2") + " " + row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn3"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to see you again, David.  This looks like the answer I've been in search of.  Let me ensure it works and if so, I'll mark this as the answer so you get awarded the bounty.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi David, I just ran into one thing I didn't consider - I'm pretty sure your solution is going to work and I'll be awarding you the bounty no matter what - quick question though: let's say I create two different entity maps, `TaskEntityMap1` and `TaskEntityMap2`; then say, in the csv file, if the first field of a given row is 1, use `TaskEntityMap1` to map that row to SQL, if it's 2, use `TaskEntityMap2`.  Both maps would map to the same SQL table, just going to different fields.  Where would I handle that logic in the code when I'm using CSVHelper, since there is no `for each` loop involved?

Comment: You would likely need to loop through each record so that you can check the first record for your mapping flag.  Check out the documentation on [Reading By Hand](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/) I would do a `Read()`, `ReadHeader()`, another `Read()`, then check your flag field by name or index. Register the particular `ClassMap`. Call `GetRecord<TaskEntity>` to add that record (instead of adding each individual property), then start your while(csv.Read()) loop to get the rest of the records.  If you need more just start a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: Hi David, thanks, that's a good point, I should have started a new question to begin with.  I'll do that.  It appears your answer above does in fact satisfy the original question so shortly I'll be marking it as answer now to award you the bounty. Thanks again!

Comment: David, in case you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190364/csvhelper-using-two-mapping-classes-and-choosing-the-mapping-based-on-the-valu

Answer (score 0):

I have used the **SqlBulkCopy** along with the **csvhelper** to dump data in to the sql server.

SqlBulkCopy is an awesome utility that writes data to the sql server from nearly any data source that can be loaded into a DataTable instance.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
if (lines.Count() == 0) 
    return;

var tableName = GetTableName(file);
var columns = lines[0].Split(',').ToList();
var table = new DataTable();
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Clear();

foreach (var c in columns)
{
    table.Columns.Add(c);
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(c, c); 
}

for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];
    // Explicitly mark empty values as null for SQL import to work
    var row = line.Split(',')
        .Select(a => string.IsNullOrEmpty(a) ? null : a).ToArray();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
sqlBulk.WriteToServer(table);
```