# CSVHelper - using two mapping classes and choosing the mapping based on the value in a field of each row of the csv file

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Using the CSVHelper .NET library with .NET Core 2.2 to parse large csv file (over 1 million rows) and write it to a SQL Server table.

I have two mapping classes:  we need to loop through each row, and if the first value of the row is 1, we need to use class map 1, and if the value is 2, we need to use class map 2.  Because CSVHelper is geared toward doing this activity in bulk, I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to use the `if` statement and `for each` loop to accomplish this task.

This what I have so far:

**SQL Entity Class**

```
public class TaskEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SqlTableColumn1 { get; set; }
    public string SqlTableColumn2 { get; set; }
}
```

**CSVHelper Mapping Class 1**

```
public sealed class TaskEntityMap1 : ClassMap<TaskEntity>
{
    public TaskEntityMap1()
    {
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn1).Name("CsvColumn1");
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn2).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn2") + " " + row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn3"));
    }
}
```

**CSVHelper Mapping Class 2**

```
public sealed class TaskEntityMap2 : ClassMap<TaskEntity>
{
    public TaskEntityMap2()
    {
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn1).Name("CsvColumn4");
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn2).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn5") + " " + row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn6"));
    }
}
```

**Program.cs** (this is what we had *before* being given the requirement for the conditional mapping)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))          
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
            header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TaskEntityMap>();

        var records = csv.GetRecords<TaskEntity>().ToList();
    }
}
```

As the above example of the `Program.cs` code demonstrates the typical ease-of-use scenario which CSVHelper seems to be designed for, I'm having difficulty conceptualizing how to use two class maps, and how to loop through each row of the csv file and choose the class map depending on the value in a column in a given row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I original heard your requirements, I thought you just need to check for the `ClassMap` once per document.  It now sounds like it will change per row.  Unfortunately, I have found once you register and start using a `ClassMap` it appears to get cached and you can't switch it half way through, so I don't think the two `ClassMaps` will work. I'll give you a couple of ways to solve it and you can let me know if either satisfies your requirements.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))          
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
            header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");

        csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TaskEntityMap>();

        var records = csv.GetRecords<TaskEntity>().ToList();
    }
}

public sealed class TaskEntityMap : ClassMap<TaskEntity>
{
    public TaskEntityMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn1).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<int>(0) == 1 ? 
            row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn1") : 
            row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn4")
            );
        Map(m => m.SqlTableColumn2).ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField<int>(0) == 1 ? 
            row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn2") + " " + row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn3") :
            row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn5") + " " + row.GetField<string>("CsvColumn6")
            );
    }
}
```

Another option would be to manually construct the `TaskEntity` objects.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\me\Documents\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))          
    {
        csv.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) =>
            header.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(".", "");

        var records = new List<TaskEntity>();

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        while (csv.Read())
        {                    
            if (csv.GetField<int>(0) == 1)
            {
                var record = new TaskEntity
                {
                    SqlTableColumn1 = csv.GetField<string>("CsvColumn1"),
                    SqlTableColumn2 = csv.GetField<string>("CsvColumn2") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("CsvColumn3")
                };
                records.Add(record);
            }
            else
            {
                var record = new TaskEntity
                {
                    SqlTableColumn1 = csv.GetField<string>("CsvColumn4"),
                    SqlTableColumn2 = csv.GetField<string>("CsvColumn5") + " " + csv.GetField<string>("CsvColumn6")
                };
                records.Add(record);
            }                    
        }
    }  // Break here.
}
```

Comment: Hi David.  So looking at your first option, it appears as though I can in theory build an if condition right into the lambda expression?  I am going to try this one first.

Comment: Yes, in fact you could set up a switch or an elseif statement if you had multiple possibilities.  Or you could process and return the value via another method.

Comment: David, I decided to give your second option a try for various reasons.  I'm trying to debug it in Visual Studio (I'm not exporting to the database yet) and I'm having trouble being able to examine what the `records` look like in VS - do I need to add some kind of return statement in order to get some results to show up in any of the VS debug windows, such as Autos?  If you can't tell, I'm still rather new to all this, so your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not getting any errors during debug - just can't see any indication of any values that would indicate it's working correctly, before I move on to the SQL export piece.

Comment: Maybe make sure you don't break outside of the using statements? If I break at the end of the using statements I can see the records.  If a break at the end of the Main method, the records have gone out of scope.

Comment: Ah I see.  I will try that!

Comment: I went with option #2.  Thanks again David!

Comment: *I have found once you register and start using a `ClassMap` it appears to get cached and you can't switch it half way through, so I don't think the two `ClassMaps` will work.* -- as of CsvHelper version 30 this seems to be possible by using `csvReader.Context.UnregisterClassMap();`.  See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76434427/3744182) to [Reading csv file that is organized differently in 2 different places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76432950/3744182).

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't appear that you can `UnregisterClassMap` once you start reading.  You _can_ register 20 different `ClassMap` to 20 _different_ classes, but you can't unregister a `ClassMap` to a specific class.  That `ClassMap` you thought you unregistered is still valid and would be used if you called `GetRecord` for that same class later in your code.